# localhost redirected you too many times while redirecting to specific URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

I created an action filter to check some statements then redirect client to specific action or route, but when I run the application browser shows this page:
[Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Baff6.png)

My code:

```cs
public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var customer = await _workContext.GetCurrentCustomerAsync();

    var vendor = _vendorRepository.GetAll()
        .FirstOrDefault(w => w.CustomerId == customer.VendorId);
    if (vendor == null)
        return;                

    if (!(vendor.ActivationDate < DateTime.Now))
        return;
    RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "CheckVendorDate");
    redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "VendorActivation");

    context.Result=new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
}
```

**Update** :

If you want to check action and controller name in OnAuthorizationAsync method , to prevent causing recursive redirection or etc , use this code :

```
 var descriptor = context?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

           var action = descriptor.ActionName;
            var controllerName = descriptor.ControllerName;
```

Comment: Try to clear cookies on the redirecting website and clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be causing recursive redirection, an additional check is needed to prevent redirection to `/VendorActivation/CheckVendorDate` if context is from that route.

```cs
if (context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "CheckVendorDate" &&
        context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "VendorActivation")
    return;
```

Comment: Problem is that "CheckVendorDate"  Action and "VendorActivationDate" controller will not call so I think checking action name and controller name is useless